# script generation in GMF

Tags: eclipse-plugin

i have created my own graphical editor using GMF.
i want to generate code based on the diagram created by editor? any pointers how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseBuilder/article.html

That page doesn't have the actual code example but the points to the necessary concepts: Builders. For example, the java compiler is hooked in through a builder that's registered for the .java type.